# sendRedirect is redirecting only Home page component but not Home page wholely

Tags: apex, visualforce, home-page-component, redirect

i was developing a home page component (for searching records) which will take any id of a particular object and redirects to the object if the id matches to any of the record id.But this is working fine when i go through normal VF page but when i make this vf page as home page component the home page component only getting redirected but not complete home page.

VF page code

```
<apex:form >
  <apex:outputLabel value="Incident Id" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <apex:inputText value="{!Id}"/>
  <apex:commandButton action="{!Search}" value="Search"/>
</apex:form>
```

controller code

```
public PageReference Search() {

        String query ='SELECT ID,Name FROM itil_b__Incident__c  WHERE Name LIKE '+'\'%'+Id+'\'';
        incidentsList=Database.Query(query);
         if(incidentsList.size()==1){
            itil_b__Incident__c incident=new itil_b__Incident__c();
            incident=incidentsList.get(0);
            Id incidentId=incident.Id;
            PageReference pr=new PageReference('/'+incidentId);
            pr.setRedirect(false);
            return pr;
         }
}
```

[image]

after hitting search

[image]

the component is only getting redirected, but i was checking is there any way to redirect the whole home page like

[image]

Comment: A [change](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Home-Page-Components-Changes-Starting-Summer-14&) was introduced in Summer '15 that meant all the sidebar components are now in an iFrame and as a result can not interact with anything outside of that iFrame.

Comment: @BarCotter thanks, this mean there is no way to achieve this or is there any custom way to interact sidebar components with anything outside of that iFrame